# How to place the input element in the middle of the two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: IMAGE OF THE WEB PAGE I WANT TO CREATE, I CREATED THAT IMAGE IN PAINT!]

I want to create a web page which takes a number as input then Even or ODD background color changes depending upon the number for eg if I enter 2 then Odd background color becomes gray and even background color becomes Green, I hope u understand what I want to do, the thing is I want to place the input field in the middle like in the picture, Can anyone help me how to do that? it would be very helpful for future purposes also, Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set in the container of the input display flex and then it will be in the middle of the page, like that:

```
 display:flex; justify-content:Center; align-items:center;
```

Comment: I tried, my text field is not getting displayed at all.

Comment: maybe position absolute

Answer (score 0):

To place the input in the middle of boxes, , you can use from position absolute, and depending on the size of the boxes, you should set 'left' & 'top' styles for input, e.g in my example:

```
<body>
    <div class="box box1">EVEN</div>
    <div class="box box2">ODD</div>
    <input type="text" name="input" />
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .box{
        float: left;
        padding: 200px;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .box1{
        background-color: green;
    }
    .box2{
        background-color: red;
    }
    input{
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        top: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added a solution below. You also had an extra closing div tag without it having a opened one, I removed that for you too.

```
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.left {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

form {
  height: 100%;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```
    <div class="split top">
        <form method ="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Id_messsage">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id=Id_message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">
            <h2>EVEN</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="split right">
        <div class="centered">
        <h2>ODD</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. add a rule for `.split.top` z-index
2. change `textarea` to `<input type="text" />`

--

```
.split.top {
 z-index: 2;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 top: 46%;
}
```

output:

[image]